# PC with 2 disks , each one with a MBR, it is possible to set one as "main"?

Tags: windows-10, boot, mbr

2 ssd in my new laptop

- new one came along with it
- old one is from my old pc

each one has a win10 installation on it, i can't boot from the new ssd anymore after connecting the old one.

is there a way to disable the MBR of the old one? i would like to keep all my data without any moving/copying etc

thank you in advance

F

Comment: New systems (since 2012) use UEFI with gpt partitioning. Old systems used MBR(msdos) partitioning. Windows only boots in UEFI boot mode from gpt drives and only in BIOS boot mode from MBR drives. You probably just have to change boot mode settings in UEFI to match the install. Typically Windows does not allow transfer to another system. It is licensed for one system, so hardware change will give issues with old drive.

Comment: Try to boot into the BIOS/UEFI and change the default boot disk.